Clarifying different forms of the Dual of a quadratic Problem
I am trying to dualize a QP where the quadratic term is in the objective and the constraints are linear where Q is symmetric positive definite.
$$
\begin{align*}
\min \quad & \frac{1}{2} x^T Q x + c^T x \\
\text{st:} \quad & A x \leq b \\
& x \geq 0
\end{align*}
$$
In this post, there is some useful work already done to show the solution, which is shown below:
$$
\begin{align*}
\max \quad &  -\frac{1}{2} (c - A^T \lambda)^T Q^{-1} (c - A^T \lambda) - b^T \lambda\\
\text{st:} \quad & \lambda \geq 0\\
\end{align*}
$$
However, I found another paper (coincidentally someone else tagged that in that same post as another answer) with a different solution which I cannot seem to reconcile. The dual there looks as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\max \quad &  -\frac{1}{2} u^T Q u + b^T \lambda\\
\text{st:} \quad & A^T\lambda - Cu \leq c\\
& \lambda \geq 0
\end{align*}
$$
Note: this paper assumes that Q is symmetric positive semi-definite but I don't see any reason why constraining it further to symmetric positive definite would invalidate this.
The paper sadly does not show the derivation so I am unable to follow it but it does seem 'similar' to the former dual problem. The one in the paper would allegedly be easier since it does not have an inverse in it.
Any help would be useful
